# ¿Cómo puedo separar 4 divs dentro de 2 columnas que están divididas en 2 divs más?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

El Bootstrap lo tengo en local por eso no se ve reflejado en el Head.

El problema es que las 4 cards no se quieren separar y cuando agrego margins simplemente se estiran.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.logo{
    max-width: 240px;
    min-width: 220px;
}
.rosa{
    background-color: rgba(205, 18, 140, 0.397);
}
.gris{
    background-color: rgba(60, 76, 80, 0.397);
}

.down{
    height: 89.30vh;
}
.fondo{
    background-image: url(/assets/header.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.spacebet{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.altura{
    height:fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.png"/>

    <title>ON SERVICE C.A. | TALLERES</title>
</head>

<!-- INICIO DEL BODY -->

<body>

<!-- NAV -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/assets/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="d-inline-block align-text-top logo">
      </a>
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
        <button class="btn rosa me-md-2" type="button">Salir</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<!-- BLOQUE DE CONTENIDO -->
<div class="container-fluid fondo">
  <div class="row down">
    <!-- BARRA IZQUIERDA -->
    <div class="col-3 rosa border border-4">
        
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary col-8 mt-4" href="#">INICIO</a>
          <a class="btn btn-secondary col-8 mt-1" href="#">Manuales</a>
          <a class="btn btn-secondary col-8 mt-1" href="#">Formatos</a>
          <a class="btn btn-secondary col-8 mt-1" href="#">Cursos</a>
          <a class="btn btn-danger col-8 mt-5" href="#">VOLVER</a>
          </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BARRA DERECHA -->
    <div class="col-9 spacebet gris border-start-0 border border-4">
      <!-- 919.500x864 PIXELES DEL BLOQUE GRIS (YA TIENE LOS BORDES DE 4PX RESTADOS)-->

      <!--Bloque Taller Izquierdo-->
      <div class="card mt-4 altura" style="max-width: 430px;">
        <!--Cuadro superior I-->
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title I</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-secondary col-5 mt-1" href="#">Entrar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Cuadro inferior III-->
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title III</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-secondary col-5 mt-1" href="#">Entrar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Bloque Taller Derecho-->
      <div class="card mt-4 altura" style="max-width: 430px;">
      <!--Cuadro superior II-->
      <div class="row g-0 separacion">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title II</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary col-5 mt-1" href="#">Entrar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Cuadro inferior IV-->
      <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title IV</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary col-5 mt-1" href="#">Entrar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
      <!--FIN BARRA CONTENIDO-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript; Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Antes deberías pasar por la sección [ask] y hacer el [tour]. Así comprobarás que tu pregunta tiene muchas deficiencias y no podemos ayudarte sin la información correcta

Comment: En lugar de agregar ruido a la pregunta, debés describir el resultado esperado y el obtenido. Leé [ask].

Comment: @padaleiana Es un nuevo usuario, y se ha esforzado (tendrias que ver su primera pregunta), lo que ocurre es que no se ha dado a entender bien, pero yo creo que lo he captado y he dejado una respuesta que creo que es lo que busca, aunque no se la explico si no me lo dice, claro, son varios cambios y seria muy largo si realmente no lo quiere así.

Comment: @masterguru es nuevo colaborador, no nuevo usuario :) Además, recuerda que las respuestas son _para todos_, no solo para el autor de la pregunta (probablemente por eso te habrán votado negativo, no sé quién fue).

Comment: Bueno, sea quien sea da igual, no me molesta y lo entiendo. Voy a redactarle la respuesta completa ahora que me ha confirmado que le sirve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que quieres algo así:

```css
.logo{
    max-width: 240px;
    min-width: 220px;
}
.rosa{
    background-color: rgba(205, 18, 140, 0.397);
}
.gris{
    background-color: rgba(60, 76, 80, 0.397);
}

.down{
    height: 89.30vh;
}
.fondo{
    background-image: url(/assets/header.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.spacebet{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.altura{
    height:fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.png" />

    <title>ON SERVICE C.A. | TALLERES</title>


  </head>

  <!-- INICIO DEL BODY -->

  <body>

    <!-- NAV -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="/assets/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="d-inline-block align-text-top logo">
        </a>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
          <button class="btn rosa me-md-2" type="button">Salir</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- BLOQUE DE CONTENIDO -->
    <div class="container-fluid fondo">
      <div class="row down">
        <!-- BARRA IZQUIERDA -->
        <div class="col-3 rosa border border-4">

          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary col-8 mt-4" href="#">INICIO</a>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary col-8 mt-1" href="#">Manuales</a>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary col-8 mt-1" href="#">Formatos</a>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary col-8 mt-1" href="#">Cursos</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger col-8 mt-5" href="#">VOLVER</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- BARRA DERECHA -->
        <div class="col-9 spacebet gris border-start-0 border border-4">
          <!-- 919.500x864 PIXELES DEL BLOQUE GRIS (YA TIENE LOS BORDES DE 4PX RESTADOS)-->

          <!--Bloque Taller Izquierdo-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-auto">


              <div class="card mt-4 me-4 altura" style="max-width: 430px;">
                <!--Cuadro superior I-->
                <div class="row g-0">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title I</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <a class="btn btn-secondary col-5 mt-1" href="#">Entrar</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--Cuadro inferior III-->
              </div>
              <div class="card mt-4 me-4 altura" style="max-width: 430px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title III</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <a class="btn btn-secondary col-5 mt-1" href="#">Entrar</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-auto">
              <!--Bloque Taller Derecho-->
              <div class="card mt-4 altura" style="max-width: 430px;">
                <!--Cuadro superior II-->
                <div class="row g-0 separacion">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title II</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <a class="btn btn-secondary col-5 mt-1" href="#">Entrar</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card mt-4 altura" style="max-width: 430px;">
                <!--Cuadro inferior IV-->
                <div class="row g-0">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title IV</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <a class="btn btn-secondary col-5 mt-1" href="#">Entrar</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--FIN BARRA CONTENIDO-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**Cambios realizados:**

1. Habias puesto los cards directamente en lugar de separarlos por columnas, y ademas tenias solo dos cards en lugar de 4, y lo que hacian era resituarse solos en el espacio que les dabas. Por eso he agregado las filas y columnas deseadas de este modo.
   Donde ponias esto:

```
<!--Bloque Taller Izquierdo-->
<div class="card mt-4 altura" style="max-width: 430px;">
```

lo he modificado por esto:

```
<!--Bloque Taller Izquierdo-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
<div class="card mt-4 me-4 altura" style="max-width: 430px;">
```

creando, de este modo una fila y una columna de ancho automático, y gracias al estilo de bootstrap `me-4` (que agrega un margen derecho de valor 4) lo he separado por su derecha de la siguiente columna que luego definiremos.
2) Donde ponias esto:

```
<!--Cuadro inferior III-->
```

he cerrado el primer card y he abierto el segundo así:

```
<!--Cuadro inferior III-->
</div>
<div class="card mt-4 me-4 altura" style="max-width: 430px;">
```

donde de nuevo puedes ver el `me-4` que nos separará horizontalmente de la siguiente columna.

3. Donde ponias esto:

```
<!--Bloque Taller Derecho-->
```

lo he cambiado por esto:

```
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <!--Bloque Taller Derecho-->
```

para cerrar tanto el anterior `col-auto` como el `row`, y a su vez, iniciar la segunda columna mediante otro `col-auto`.

4. Y después, donde ponias esto:

```
<!--Cuadro inferior IV-->
```

lo he modificado por esto:

```
</div>
<div class="card mt-4 altura" style="max-width: 430px;">
<!--Cuadro inferior IV-->
```

por lo mismo de antes, para cerrar el tercer **card** y abrir el cuarto **card**.

5. Y finalmente, donde ponias esto:

```
<!--FIN BARRA CONTENIDO-->
```

lo he cambiado por esto:

```
  </div>
</div>
<!--FIN BARRA CONTENIDO-->
```

para cerrar el `col-auto` y el `row` creados para la segunda columna.

Comment: Hola, si funciono! Por favor cuentame, como lo hiciste?! Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Vale, perfecto, tardare un poquito, han sido varias cosas a tener en cuenta... a ver si puedo redactarlo bien para que se entienda....

Comment: ya he leído a detalle los cambios, definitivamente tengo muchisimo que aprender, mil gracias por tu aporte y tu tiempo para responder!